# How to fill missing value with KNN in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, missing-data, knn

I'm trying to  fill missing values with KNN in python so I wrote this code but it doesn't work . I get this error "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'normal'" .what should I do?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'df.csv')
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=5)
df = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(df),columns = df.columns)
```

Comment: What exactly does "it doesn't work" mean? _How_ does it "not work"? What behaviour are you expecting? What happens instead?

Comment: @ForceBru I get this error "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'normal'"

Comment: Could you share the first few rows of your `df.csv` file? It sounds like your data is being interpreted as strings.

Answer (score 1):

Usually to replace NaN values, we use the `sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer` which can replace `NaN` values with the value of your choice (mean , median of the sample, or any other value you would like).

```py
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
df = imp.fit_transform(df)
```

Comment: This is preprocessing to be inserted between dataframe creation and the intented use (KNNImputer, model training, etc...). Do not hesitate to provide more info, namely on on current dataframe structure (like a df.head() output)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how your df look like but I guess  you might be have to use Ordinal or Label Encoders as KNN imputer does not work with text data.

Here is a guide for you:

https://medium.com/@kyawsawhtoon/a-guide-to-knn-imputation-95e2dc496e

Answer (score 0):

The KNN method will compute the distance between vectors, so if your data is categorical, you should convert it to numerical. For example, if the string stands labels, you could use one-hot to encode the labels.

There is another python package that implements KNN imputation method:
[impyte](https://impyte.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)